# How to return a struct in prolog

Tags: prolog

What I've been told to do is "travel a list of workers represented by a structure "worker(Name, Time)" "

I want to return something with this form:

```
couple(Worker1,Worker2,TI)
```

And I feel I either haven't seen any examples of this in prolog or I'm missing something. Like, I know to return lists, but not lists of structs, which is what I understand I have to do.

Is this possible in prolog? Could I get an example since I do not quite get it?

Summing up: I want to travel a list of so called structs, and return a struct that contains pairs of elements found in said list of structs. I leave out what I have to do to select which pair for now to focus on this concrete problem but I could post it, too, if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog actually has neither return values nor structs, but you can use unification and complex terms, respectively, to achieve the same effect.

You could pass in a term with free variables, e.g. `couple(Worker1, Worker2, TI)`, and let the predicate set those variables with values. Or for a list of terms, pass in an empty list and another free variable, and append a new term as head at each recursive step, and then when the trivial case is reached, unify the free variable with the list you built.

A very simple example to demonstrate the basic technique would be:

```
% Trivial case: unify the built list with the Result variable.
make_worker_pairs([], Result, Result).

% Recursive case: if list has at least one worker, ...
make_worker_pairs([worker(Name, Time)|T], Accu, Result) :-
    % make a couple, append it to the intermediate result (Accumulator),
    % and process the rest (Tail) of the list.
    make_worker_pairs(T, 
                      [couple(worker(Name, Time), worker(Name, Time), Time)|Accu],
                      Result).
```

To call it:

```
?- make_worker_pairs([worker(mike, 6), worker(laura, 9)], [], Result).
```